# Accessing Google Sheet to Create a sheet(GCP)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-sheets-api

I want to Fetch data from firestore and append all the data in a new Google sheet.
Creating sheet is where i am finding problem.

as far as i have researched, i ve found out there are 3 methods to access google api,
1)API  key
2)Service account
3)Oauth
Ignoring API key,

While using service account, i have found out that sheet which is getting created will be owned by service account so no one else can remove it.

when using Oauth, i have used OAuth json credential from GCP , in which when i try to use it in local host, it shows me Google's Logging screen, but when i deploy it in app engine, it doesnt redirect it to logging screen.
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs
this is the document where i find the approach.

One more method i have found i.e. Access token. i.e. putting access token in

```
const sheets = google.sheets({ version: "v4",headers:{ Authorization:`Bearer ${accessToken}` }});
```

but that wont be possible, as in Front end i am using

```
auth.onAuthStateChanged
```

which doesnt provide me Access token just the ID token.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your `auth.onAuthStateChanged` code it looks like you're using Firebase Authentication to sign in on the frontend.

Firebase Authentication is based around JWT ID tokens, which are not the same as OAuth tokens. You can't use such an ID token to make calls to the Google Sheets API.

If you're signing in with Google or another OAuth provider on the frontend, you can capture the OAuth token from that provider before you sign in to Firebase with it, and then use the OAuth token to call the Google Sheets API.